# Android Studio: geolocation not working. Failing to get geolocation in Webview

Tags: java, android, html, geolocation

I'm using a WebView to show different html pages. In these i'm implementing a map from mapbox, but it won't find the users location.
Even if I open up different https pages in the WebView the location will never be found on these sides.
I allowed location permissions and added different user-permissions to the Android Manifest.

These pages locate the location of my devices fine, if i dont open them up from the WebView in my app im working on.

The page i created myself includes a map which works with the api of leaflet.com.

This is some simple Code im trying to make it work with.

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        //myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/leaflet.html");
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://mylocation.org");

        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

}
```

And this is the Code of the manifest.xml where i gave different user-permissions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.hsos.spotit">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I hope someone can help me with that, because im spending hours to figure this out. There are nearly no questions in the internet which come close to this or any solution.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a WebChromeClient method to request the appropriate permissions:

```
private String geolocationOrigin;
private GeolocationPermissions.Callback geolocationCallback;

WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

//required for Geolocation
webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyGeoWebChromeClient());


public class MyGeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        // Geolocation permissions coming from this app's Manifest will only be valid for devices with
        // API_VERSION < 23. On API 23 and above, we must check for permissions, and possibly
        // ask for them.
        String perm = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, perm) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // we're on SDK < 23 OR user has already granted permission
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        } else {
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, perm)) {
                // ask the user for permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{perm}, REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);

                // we will use these when user responds
                geolocationOrigin = origin;
                geolocationCallback = callback;
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION:
            boolean allow = false;
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // user has allowed this permission
                allow = true;
            }
            if (geolocationCallback != null) {
                // call back to web chrome client
                geolocationCallback.invoke(geolocationOrigin, allow, false);
            }
            break;

    }
}
```